# getting a handle on an element in the context of another

Tags: puppeteer

I have a typical page containing sections of label/field pairs but with the same label name in different sections. The sections have are named so I can identify them using the name. The HTML is structured so that the section name is a sibling of another element containing the label/fields

```
<div class="section">Business Address<\div>
<div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="label">Country<\div>
    <input type="text">
....
```

If I could identify the label element using a selector only I can do something like: -

```
const siblingHandle = page.evaluateHandle(() => {
  const sectionLabelHandle = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.blah')).find(el=>el.textContent.includes('section label name'))
  return sectionLabelHandle.nextElementSibling
})
const label = await siblingHandle.$('label selector')
```

But what I need is a handle on the label element so that I can get its sibling field so I can type a value in it.

I can't use siblingHandle.$eval() as it doesn't return a handle.

I've also considered using page.waitForFunction, passing in the handle so that can be used instead of 'document'

```
const labelHandle = page.waitForFunction(
  handle => Array.from(handle.querySelectorAll('sel')).find(el=>el.textContent.includes('text'),
  {},
  siblingHandle
)
```

but I get a cycling JSON error if I do that.

So, a couple of questions,

1) Is there any way to get siblings in Puppeteer without having to use nextElementSibling in an evaluate function?

2) How can I search for an element containing specified text, but in the context of a parent handle rather than document?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use the selector of the element in particular?

From your snippet above, I should be able to do 

 >>>> await page.type('div > div.field > input', 'inputted text', {delay: 100}) <<<<<
Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Xpath selectors as opposed to CSS selectors can answer both of your questions.

Search for an element via specified text:
`const xpathWithText = '//div[text()="Country"]';`

Using it to get the next sibling:
`const xPathTextToSibling = '//div[text()="Country"]/following-sibling::input';`

In practice:

```
const myInput = await page.waitForXPath(xPathTextToSibling);
await myInput.type('Text to type');
```

You should not need to search for an element with specific text in the context of a parent handle because the second selector I used above will give you a handle of the element you want to type in directly.